# Jquery data tables child rows - TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'm[n].style')

Tags: jquery, datatables

im attempting to create a a datable with child rows, and each child row has a table with multiple rows in, my code looks like it should work according to the sample on https://datatables.net/examples/api/row_details.html however im receiving the below error

```
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'm[n].style')
```

fiddle is here: https://jsfiddle.net/tpmwL9qc/1/
bu the fiddle gives a different error, possibly because im trying to load via a json array instead of an Ajax request?

here's my code:

html

```
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="d-flex flex-row justify-content-between">
                    <h4 class="card-title"><i class="fa fa-fighter-jet"></i> Device Inventory  </h4>
                </div>
                <p>&nbsp;</p>
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table width="100%" class="table  dtr-inline" id="device_inventory" role="grid" style="width: 100%;">   
                        <thead>         
                            <tr>
                                <th>Site</th>   
                                <th>Hostname</th>
                                <th>Model</th>  
                                <th>Serial No</th>
                                <th>Mgmt IP</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Datatables JavaScript -->
<script>
/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    var row_data =  '<table>'+
        '<tr>' +
            '<th>Part No</th>' +
            '<th>Description</th>' +
            '<th>Serial No</th>' +
        '</tr>'
        $.each(d.parts, function(idx, part){
            row_data += '<tr>' +
            '<td>' + part.part_no + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + part.description + '</td>' +
            '<td>' + part.serial_no + '</td>' +
        '</tr>'
        });
        row_data += '</table>'
    return row_data
}
 
$(document).ready(function() {
    var table = $('#device_inventory').DataTable( {
        "ajax": "{% url 'config:device_inventory_data' %}",
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "site" },
            { "data": "host_name" },
            { "data": "model" },
            { "data": "serial_no" },
            { "data": "mgmt_ip" }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );
     
    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#device_inventory tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );
 
        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );
} );
</script>
```

here's my json

```
[
    {
        "site": "HQ",
        "hostname": "HQ-ACS",
        "model": "Cisco - VMWare",
        "serial_no": null,
        "mgmt_ip": "10.10.10.100",
        "parts": []
    },
    {
        "site": "HQ",
        "hostname": "HQ-VPN",
        "model": "Cisco - CISCO2951/K9",
        "serial_no": "****",
        "mgmt_ip": "172.16.1.1",
        "parts": [
            {
                "part_no": "CISCO2951/K9",
                "description": "CISCO2951/K9",
                "serial_no": "****"
            },
            {
                "part_no": "EHWIC-1GE-SFP-CU",
                "description": "Enhanced High Speed WAN Interface Card-1 Port Gigabit Ethernet SFP/Cu on Slot 0 SubSlot 0",
                "serial_no": "****"
            },
            {
                "part_no": "EHWIC-4ESG",
                "description": "4 Port GE Non-POE EHWIC Switch on Slot 0 SubSlot 1",
                "serial_no": "****"
            },
            {
                "part_no": "PWR-2921-51-AC",
                "description": "C2921/C2951 AC Power Supply",
                "serial_no": "****"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "site": "HQ",
        "hostname": "HQ-FW-02",
        "model": "Checkpoint - Firewall",
        "serial_no": null,
        "mgmt_ip": "10.10.10.1",
        "parts": []
    },
    {
        "site": "HQ",
        "hostname": "HQ-RTR-01",
        "model": "Cisco - CISCO3945-CHASSIS",
        "serial_no": "****",
        "mgmt_ip": "1.1.1.1",
        "parts": [
            {
                "part_no": "CISCO3945-CHASSIS",
                "description": "CISCO3945-CHASSIS",
                "serial_no": "****"
            },
            {
                "part_no": "C3900-SPE150/K9",
                "description": "Cisco Services Performance Engine 150 for Cisco 3900 ISR on Slot 0",
                "serial_no": "****"
            },
            {
                "part_no": "EHWIC-1GE-SFP-CU",
                "description": "Enhanced High Speed WAN Interface Card-1 Port Gigabit Ethernet SFP/Cu on Slot 0 SubSlot 0",
                "serial_no": "****"
            },
            {
                "part_no": "PWR-3900-AC",
                "description": "C3900 AC Power Supply 1",
                "serial_no": "****"
            },
            {
                "part_no": "PWR-3900-AC",
                "description": "C3900 AC Power Supply 2",
                "serial_no": "*****"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes regarding items that you can fix, based on the code in your question (not the fiddle):

---

The column definition:

```
{ "data": "host_name" }
```

should be as follows, to match your JSON:

```
{ "data": "hostname" }
```

---

The DataTable definition includes 6 columns, starting with an empty column:

```
{ ..., "data": null, "defaultContent": '' },
```

But your HTML table does not have a column for this - so you can add it at the start of your `<tr>` section:

```
<tr>
    <th></th>   
    <th>Site</th>   
    <th>Hostname</th>
    <th>Model</th>  
    <th>Serial No</th>
    <th>Mgmt IP</th>
</tr>
```

This is where the circular buttons/images will be displayed.

---

The demo (in the link) needs you to provide the `open.png` and `close.png` graphics for the buttons. I don't see them (or the related CSS) in the fiddle code.

See the demo's CSS tab for details.

Even without the icons you should be able to click on each cell in column 1 to open and close the child rows.

---

Assuming you resolve all the above items...

The code to create the child tables looks good - for example, I got this for the 2nd row:

[image]

---

**Update:**

Looking at the code in the Fiddle:

You should change the order of resources, so that jQuery is declared first, before the DataTables JS library. This will resolve the error stating that "DataTables is not a function".

Comment: Thanks! the JS Fiddle is working now, however my dev app is not, theres a lot more data in the dev app and the console is showing 'TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'f.length')' in the DataTables js, would you have any idea where to look?

Comment: I needed to add { "data": the_data } to the json repsone